# Die Bedeutung von "von hinten nach vorne"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Er fragt sich **von hinten nach vorne** durch die Schlange an der Kasse.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and explain what exactly is unclear to you about this phrase and can not be answered using a standard dictionary?

Comment: BTW: I can imagine that it should be *Schlange* (queue & snake), not *Schnecke* (snail). And don't forget to uppercase nouns in German :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Er fragt sich von hinten nach vorne durch die **Schlange** an der *K*asse.

Er spricht den Letzten in der Schlange an:

> Ich habe nur ein Teil, lassen Sie mich vor? — Ja.

Er spricht den Vorvorletzten in der Schlange an:

> Ich habe nur ein Teil, lassen Sie mich vor? — Ja.

Er spricht den Fünftletzten in der Schlange an:

> Ich habe nur ein Teil, lassen Sie mich vor? — Ja.

…

Comment: Also kurz gesagt gibt der Ausdruck "von hinten nach vorne" die **Richtung** an, in der etwas passiert. Zuerst die Person hinten, ...., dann die Person vorne.